# Traceroute an IP address with apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, traceroute

Is it possible to get the traceroute from an incoming http request in tomcat? What I would like to get is a list of all routing points that a http request took.

Is that somehow technically possible or with some other http server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the IP address that the request came from, and you can perform a traceroute back to that IP address. However, that doesn't guarantee that the the incoming request took the same route - asymmetric routing happens frequently.

I have to ask, though - why do you care what route the traffic took?

Comment: Well, actually I would like to determine the geo location of the requests caller by ip address. I thought tracerouting would be a good idea however it is a litte stupid for this because getting the callers ip address can be simply determined from the request... thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: There are plenty of services that you can subscribe to that will let you translate IP address into (rough) geographic locations.